# C++ insertion sort error function not working

Tags: c++

The program just shows a weird error like:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
```

Code:

```
void sortlist(vector<int> &list) { // for sorting
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        temp = list.at(i);
        j = i - 1;
        while (temp < list.at(j) && j >= 0) {
            list.at(j + 1) = list.at(j);
            j = j - 1;
        }
        list.at(j + 1) = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: better dont call a variable `list`, especially when you have a `using namespace std;` somewhere

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, while observing the values of all variables? 2) How do you know that the exception comes from this piece of code? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: `uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector` means you are trying to access an element of your vector that doesn't exist. The index you are using is either < 0 or >= `list.size()`

Comment: @ThomasSablik vectors are indexed by an unsigned integer type, so out of range means that it's always `index >= list.size()`.

Comment: By the by, there already is a method to sort `std::vector<int>`s: Just use `std::sort(list.begin(), list.end());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`temp < list.at(j)` is out of bounds for `j == -1`, because `j >= 0` is too late.

In general when you do such manual bounds checking, the bounds check should always come first, not after you use the index:

```
while ( j >= 0 && temp < list.at(j))
```

Actually I dont understand what is "weird" about the error you get. The only motivation to use `at` is to get exactly that exception. Wether caught or not it will tell you that you went out of bounds. Using a debugger should have helped you to spot where exactly the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Check this condition:

```
while ( temp < list.at(j) && j >= 0 )
```

`j >= 0` is very important as it prevents you from running some code when `j` becomes -1.

Now, you would not want `list.at(j)` to be called before checking `j` being `>= 0`.

The thing is, `&&` first evaluates the left-side before deciding to evaluate or not the right-side.

So, you should reorder those two.